# Is the source list of "Oxford English Corpus" public available?

Tags: corpora, resource-request

The Oxford English Corpus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Corpus) is a text corpus of 21st century English, used by the makers of the Oxford English Dictionary and by Oxford University Press's language research program.

I [googled](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=source%20list%20of%20%22Oxford%20English%20Corpus%22&btnG=) the source list of that and didn't find an answer, is that information public available?